# No iAds in apps downloaded from few countries

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, iad

My apps on iPhone and iPad app are receiving iAds in UK and US. But there is no ad in apps downloaded on iPhone/iPad in India.

In iTunes Connect, I could see that there are ad requests from different countries but only US and UK have got impressions count almost equal to ad requests. But 0 impressions for all other countries.

Is there any country based setting I need to check so that ads are visible in all countries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not currently available in India.

> iAd advertisements are currently being served to apps on the U.S.,
>   U.K., Germany, Italy, Spain, France, and Japan App Stores.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/iad/